# Do I need to create a new signing key for every new application?

Tags: android, react-native, sign

I've just finished my second react native app and going to release its android version. Should I create a new signing key or I can use my previus project key?

Comment: Can you can, if you should I think it really depends on your situation, it sounds like an opinion based question

Comment: I agree, I've added an answer with an explanation. It depends on a situation.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that stops you to use one keystore for all apps, but it's not good practice.

With one key, it's easier for you.

With different keys, you can transfer just one of your apps to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new signing key. You could use one signing key for every app.

Answer (score 0):

I recently heard a case where a company sold an app to another company, and was more than happy to find out its engineers used separate project keys for all apps; the company basically sold the specific key along with the code and the intellectual property without affecting the rest.

Switching to a new set of keys for an already deployed app is not possible, as it is seemingly tied to the identification of apps for updates, preventing updates from third parties; unfortunately, I do not have a link at hand that documents this.

Answer (score 0):

[Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#considerations) say:

> You should sign all of your apps with the same certificate throughout
>   the expected lifespan of your applications. There are several reasons
>   why you should do so:
>
> App upgrade: When the system is installing an update to an app, it
>   compares the certificate(s) in the new version with those in the
>   existing version. The system allows the update if the certificates
>   match. If you sign the new version with a different certificate, you
>   must assign a different package name to the application—in this case,
>   the user installs the new version as a completely new application.
>
> App modularity: Android allows apps signed by the same certificate to
>   run in the same process, if the applications so requests, so that the
>   system treats them as a single application. In this way you can deploy
>   your app in modules, and users can update each of the modules
>   independently.
>
> Code/data sharing through permissions: Android provides
>   signature-based permissions enforcement, so that an app can expose
>   functionality to another app that is signed with a specified
>   certificate. By signing multiple apps with the same certificate and
>   using signature-based permissions checks, your apps can share code and
>   data in a secure manner.

At these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35740615/8770663) is another opinion:

> I'd recommend using different keystores if they are totally unrelated
>   apps. If you end up selling one of the apps, you can give away the
>   corresponding keystore without compromising the security of your other
>   apps.